# Almacenar información en archivos de texto con python [3.6] [io,os]

Tags: python, python-3.x

PYTHON 3.6

Hola, estoy intentando almacenar la información que se genera al ejecutar comandos en un archivo de texto

por ejemplo :

```
import os, io

file = open("archivoGenerado.txt","w")
comandos = ["comando1","comando2","comando3"]

for comando in comandos:
    file.write(os.system(comando))
file.close()
```

Mi objetivo es almacenar el resultado que se genera al ejecutar el comando del sistema, sin embargo, no logra almacenarlo.

espero me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El retorno de `os.system` depende del sistema y puede ser simplemente 0 si el comando se ejecutó correctamente. Realmente  en la práctica está considerado como "deprecated" dadas sus limitaciones, en su lugar usa el módulo [**`subprocess`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess).

Por ejemplo `subporcess.run` o `subprocess.Popen` permiten redirigir *stdout*, *stderr* y *stdin* de forma simple a dónde tu quieras, incluida la terminal actual dónde se está ejecutando el script:

```
import subprocess
import shlex


comandos = ["comando1","comando2", "comando3"]

with open("archivoGenerado.txt", "w") as outfile:
    for comando in comandos:
        subprocess.run(shlex.split(comando),
                       stdout=outfile,
                       stderr=outfile)

        outfile.write(f"\n{'='*100}\n")
        outfile.flush()
```

[`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) también podría ser útil.

> **Nota:** las dos últimas líneas solo generan una línea  `=====...` para separar las salidas de los distintos comandos. Esto se puede hacer solo si el método usado para ejecutar el comando espera a que este retorne, como hace 
>   `subprocess.run`.

Comment: Excelente! ... me resultó con tus módulos, investigaré mas sobre ellos eso si para sacar mejor provecho.